# Fortran Extensions in >=Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, fortran, f2py

I am attempting to build Python extensions that include f90 code for Python 3.5 and newer. Previously, I was able to use the MinGWPy project to build extensions with gfortran. However, MinGWPy doesn't support Python 3.5 and newer, and has recently been discontinued.

How can I build Python extensions for version 3.5 and newer that include Fortran?
Specifically keep in mind the build system used: `numpy.distutils` and how it statically links Fortran libraries directly to a wrapper compiled with the default C compiler.

Comment: *"So far as I can find out, it is no longer possible to compile fortran extensions..."* Why do you believe so? What kind of problems did you encounter? In which ways exactly is the C compiler incompatible with gfortran? I was using gfortran code with Microsoft C++ code using the Fortran_C interop (aka iso c binding) just fine.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue4709

Comment: So it is more about gcc and not gfortran. It is about the C wrapper layer. In that case can't you just define the macro mentioned in the first comment in your link? Please do include all important information you have in the question, the question is pretty unclear without that link.

Comment: http://mingwpy.github.io/proposal_december2015.html This link is a bit clearer. I asked exactly the question for which I wanted an answer. If there is a complex method requiring lot of modifications to my code then it isn't a solution I can use.

Comment: *"I asked exactly the question for which I wanted an answer. "* Please do understand that if a question needs clarifications in the comments, it ia likely incomplete or lacks motivating information which is often very important. Comments can be deleted at any time, that is why it should be within the question, not in the comments.

Comment: @VladimirF This is a perfectly valid question for those that know the background. Yes, you probably have access to intel fortran, so this wouldn't affect you. But when you are using MSVC to build Python extensions that have fortran code, there was no free option available until recently.

Comment: *"for those that know the background:* What I was asking for was to include the background into the question, nothing more.

Comment: It the question acceptable now? The main reason your idea wouldn't work is that Python-based build systems are pretty terrible but there's a huge legacy code requirement.

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: Thank you for the edits and removing the downvote. One point though: I was using the compilers and toolchain from MinGW, not the MinGWPy project.

Answer (score 1):

You can build Python extensions for 3.5+ with flang. That's:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install flang
```

Disclosure: I am a contributor to the flang project.

Comment: This looks interesting. Does flang work with f2py 'out of the box'?

Comment: flang requires numpy 1.14

Comment: It works!! Many thanks @xaav. Would you recommend to keep the mingwpy C compiler or install the Microsoft tools?